# How to display the sum of all expenses in a chart

Tags: python, django, chart.js

So I have a project of building a web app that tracks expenses and I am at a point where I have incorporated a chart but I also want to display the total sum of all expenses (which is dynamic) along side the chart but I am having a hard time figuring out how I should do it because I am kind of a beginner at this.

Here is my js file for the chart:

```
const renderChart = (data, labels) => {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Monthly Expenses',
        data: data,
      }],
    },
    options: {
      borderWidth: 10,
      borderRadius: 2,
      hoverBorderWidth: 0,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
      },
    },
  });
}


const getChartData=() => {
  console.log("fetching")
  fetch('expense_category_summary')
      .then((res)=>res.json())
      .then((results)=>{
        console.log("results", results);
        const category_data = results.expense_category_data;
        const [labels, data] = [
            Object.keys(category_data),
            Object.values(category_data),
        ];
        renderChart(data, labels);
  });
};
document.onload = getChartData();
```

Please help, Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should also post what you get by `console.log("results", results)` (the text of the log, not an image).